# How do i tell if a network is not sorting network?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, parallel-computing

For most sorting network diagrams how do you work out that it is not a sorting network? What is the method to work it out ?

Comment: `For most sorting network diagrams how do you work out that it is not a sorting network?` you don't: it wouldn't have been a diagram of a sorting network to begin with. Maybe a "network of conditional exchangers"/"pair sorters"? (I seem to remember a different interpretation of *2-sorting* ("$n$-sorting"), suggesting not to use that here.) D.E. Knuth featured sorting networks way back, including [the zero-one principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Zero-one_principle).

Comment: (I never followed the thought whether it is always possible to order sorting networks left-to-right.)